Show that $F(x,y)$ is an integral for a linear map $L(\mathbf{x})$

A function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is called an integral for a
linear map $L$ if $F\circ L(\textbf{x})=F(\textbf{x})$, i.e., $F$ is
constant along orbits of $L$. Show that  \begin{equation}
     F\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\
         y
     \end{pmatrix}=x^2+y^2 \end{equation}
is an integral for  \begin{equation}
    L(\mathbf{x})=\begin{pmatrix}
         0&1\\
         -1 & 0
     \end{pmatrix}\textbf{x} \end{equation}

$L(\textbf{x})$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_{1,2}=\pm i$. Consider the real valued function $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Since we can claim that there exists a $v<1$ such that if $\epsilon>0$ is small enough, we have
\begin{equation}
    F\circ L(\textbf{x})\leq v F(\textbf{x})
\end{equation}
This gives the computation:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
    &F\circ L(\textbf{x})=\lambda^2(x^2+y^2) \ \ \ \ \\
    &v =\lambda^2 \\
    &F\circ L(\textbf{x})=vF\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\
y
    \end{pmatrix}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
This gives the inequality for $\textbf{x}\ne0$
\begin{equation}
    F\circ L(\textbf{x})\leq v^nF(\textbf{x})
\end{equation}
Hence, $F\circ L^n(\textbf{x})\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, and $F(\textbf{x})=0$ for $\textbf{x}=0$.
But if I insert the eigenvalues, I cannot see that the inequality still holds.

Since
$$
L\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\
         y
     \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
        y\\
         -x
     \end{pmatrix},
$$
we have
$$
(F\circ L)\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\
         y
     \end{pmatrix}=y^2+(-x)^2=F\begin{pmatrix}
        x\\
         y
     \end{pmatrix},
$$
that is, $F\circ L=F$.
Nothing else is needed.
